# Optimize SQL with sub queries to?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have following two tables in the bottom of the post. The siteUsers table have a type column that can be "Member" or "Owner". I am looking for a SQL that shows how many members and owners each site has. I could do something like:

```
select 
    sites.Url,
    (select count(*) from siteusers where type='member' and siteusers.siteid=sites.siteid) as members,
    (select count(*) from siteusers where type='owners' and siteusers.siteid=sites.siteid) as owners
    from sites
    group by sites.url
```

However this is extreemly slow. Is there a faster and smarter way?

Sites table:

```
SiteId  int Unchecked
SPOSiteId   uniqueidentifier    Checked
Url nvarchar(MAX)   Checked
```

SiteUsers Table:

```
SiteUserId  int Unchecked
Type    nvarchar(256)   Checked
Name    nvarchar(512)   Checked
Email   nvarchar(512)   Checked
Host    nvarchar(256)   Checked
SiteId  int Checked
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do conditional aggregation with `JOIN` :

```
SELECT s.Url,
       SUM(CASE WHEN su.type ='member' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as members,
       SUM(CASE WHEN su.type ='owners' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as owners
FROM sites s INNER JOIN
     siteuser su
     ON su.siteid = s.siteid
GROUP BY s.Url;
```

However, you want index on `sites(Url), siteuser(type)` for better performance.

If the `url` is unique in `sites`, then this should be fast with the right indexes:

```
select s.Url,
    (select count(*) from siteusers su where su.type = 'member' and su.siteid = s.siteid) as members,
    (select count(*) from siteusers su where su.type = 'owners' and su.siteid = s.siteid) as owners
from sites s;
```

The right index is on `siteusers(siteid, type)`.  Of course, this assumes that `url` is unique which may not be the case.

Comment: You totally right I dont know why I have group by when all is unique!

Answer (score 2):

One way is:

```
select s.Url,
       sum(case when su.type = 'member' then 1 else 0 end) as members,
       sum(case when su.type = 'owners' then 1 else 0 end) as owners,
from sites s left join
     siteusers su
     on s.siteid = su.siteid
where su.type in ('member', 'owners')
group by s.url;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Group By

```
 select s.Url,su.type, count(*)

 from sites s join
 siteusers su
 on s.siteid = su.siteid

 group by s.url,su.type
```

Comment: OOhh guyyss som many good answers! Damn I can only mark one answers :( But thanks all highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I'd first check that proper primary keys and indexes are built:

- table `Sites` should have primary key `SiteId`
- table `SiteUsers` should have primary key `SiteUserId`
- table `SiteUsers` should have index on `SiteId, type`

then you can run following query to get results:

```
select s.url, t.members, t.owners
from Sites s inner join
(
  select
    SiteId, 
    sum(case when Type = 'member' then 1 else 0 end) as members,
    sum(case when Type = 'owners' then 1 else 0 end) as owners
  from SiteUsers
  group by SiteId
) t on s.SiteId = t.SiteId
```

this way you avoid `group by` varchar column

sample fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/0b9b7/4

Comment: That runs very fast! The index and PK was allready in place. Sweet!